# trazar varias rutas swift

Tags: swift, xcode, geolocalización, map, swift4

quisiera saber como trazar ruta como lo hace google maps o mapas de iOS para generar el km y los min y tener la opción de buscar dos lugares estoy usando mapKit

```css
import UIKit
import MapKit
import FirebaseAuth
import CoreLocation


class mapiVC: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   
    @IBAction func sigout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "eit", sender: self)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bienvenid: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MPs: MKMapView!
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
   
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
        let mylocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mylocation, span: span)
        MPs.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.MPs.showsUserLocation = true
    }

   
     @IBAction func busqueda(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        
        
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    

    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // crear anotacion
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
        
        let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        
        activeSearch.start { (response, error) in
            
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            
            if response == nil
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove annotations
                let annotations = self.MPs.annotations
                self.MPs.removeAnnotations(annotations)
                
                //Getting data
                let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
                let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude
                
                // crear anotacion
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = searchBar.text
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude! , longitude!)
                self.MPs.addAnnotation(annotation)
                
                // zooming in on annotation
                let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
                let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
                self.MPs.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```